# Visual Studio 2017 enterprise can not add reference

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I want to add a reference in a project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. I get the following error:

```
"The operation could not be completed"
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding solution, restart computer, delete `bin` and `obj` folder and all `.suo` files. Also there is no error in my `Web.config` file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I got help from microsoft support.

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt as administrator
2. Goto the path of your visual studio installation, standard is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\
3. Select your installation type and goto \Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
4. Run command: gacutil -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll
5. Run command gacutil -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

This fixed it for me

Comment: Thanks :)...fixed my issue

Comment: VS2017 may need to be restarted.

Comment: I get "'gacutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Gilgames You need some environment that has gacutil. I used the "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019", but it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @Gilgames I found it under the Windows SDK directory, which made the place where I ran the command, and the command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\gacutil.exe" -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below steps and it worked for me.

1. Select the project in which you want to add the reference, then right click on it, Unload the project.
2. Again go to the same project, right click and then you can see the option of Edit the project. Click on it and for reference click on this link-
   [Project_Name.csproj file(C#)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPmfi.png)
3. Now manually include the namespaces or any project reference present in the same solution which you want to use in the current project. For reference, click on this link- [Add the references:See Highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1zF5.png)
4. In order to create the Project UID(Unique ID)- {1140F306-2341-4D3D-BEC7-9CCA3C2AC00E},
   Go to Tools -- Create GUID -- Select GUID Format i.e. Registry Format and then click on copy and then paste it into your .csproj file. For reference click on this link-
   [GUID Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4CN.png)
5. Then save the .csproj file and then right click on the project in which you have done changes and Reload the project.
6. After following the above steps, right click on the references and you can see the namespace or project reference which you have given in .csproj file

I hope, the above solution will work for others as well.