# Adding reference to Nunit Test project - "operation could not be completed" error

Tags: c#, testing, reference, nunit, visual-studio-2017

I use VS 2017. I have created Nunit.Test project, and I want to add reference to my main project, of which methods I want to test. When I am trying "Add > Reference" an error occurs, with dialog:

**The operation could not be completed.**

I tried to check versions of Nunit or reinstall it, but it did't help. Some ideas?

EDIT: problem solved. Solution found in: [Visual Studio 2017 enterprise can not add reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636090/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-can-not-add-reference)
(Please moderate, if needed)

Comment: This needs more detail in order to give a good answer.

Comment: Have you tried to add references directly in the `.csproj`?

Comment: @PaulRoub - but here, it was specified to Nunit project type. Maybe one more redirect will be helpful in the future?...

Comment: All the more reason to accept the duplicate. This question will remain, as a signpost linking people to the other question and its answers.