# Adding service reference doesn't work in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I click to add service reference in asp.net web application project a window opens titled "Add Service Reference" but nothing appears except title and "Not Responding" is shown next to "Add Service Reference" title. After some times it stops saying "Visual Studio 2017 stopped working" and causes restarting Visual Studio.  I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636090/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-can-not-add-reference) steps but could solve this problem. I searched it for couple of days but couldn't find a solution and eventually I thought to ask here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks